# Progress bar width animation in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am developing a website in this **I am trying to add a progress-bar (animation) style in box-shadow inset using CSS**.
But it is not done perfectly.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="box-shadow: rgb(112, 173, 71) 6px 0px 0px inset;">
      <span style="padding-left:10px;font-size:25px">Style one</span>
    </td>
    <td style="box-shadow: rgb(112, 173, 71) 6px 0px 0px inset;">
      <span style="padding-left:10px;font-size:25px">Style two</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

[image] **I am trying this strips style in box-shadow inset**

Comment: where u want to add progress bar?

Comment: why not background?

Comment: I want progress bar style on box-shadow, I don't want progress bar only strip style on box-shadow.

Comment: below code, please see. if u change few pixels u get  the background color variation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider background instead of box-shadow then simply adjust the size using `background-size`

```css
td {
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,green 0 10px,darkgreen 10px 20px) 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-size:80% 100%;">
      <span style="padding-left:10px;font-size:25px">Style one</span>
    </td>
    <td style="background-size:20% 100%;">
      <span style="padding-left:10px;font-size:25px">Style two</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

And with animation:

```css
td {
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
td:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:var(--p);
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,green 0 10px,darkgreen 10px 20px) 0 0/200% 100% no-repeat;
  z-index:-1;
  animation:change 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes change {
  to {
    background-position:right;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="--p:80%;">
      <span style="padding-left:10px;font-size:25px">Style one</span>
    </td>
    <td style="--p:20%;">
      <span style="padding-left:10px;font-size:25px">Style two</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Another kind of animation without transparency and without pseudo element:

```css
td {
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) right/calc(100% - var(--p)) 100% no-repeat,
    repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,green 0 10px,darkgreen 10px 20px) 0 0/200% 100% no-repeat;
  animation:change 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes change {
  to {
    background-position:right;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="--p:80%;">
      <span style="padding-left:10px;font-size:25px">Style one</span>
    </td>
    <td style="--p:20%;">
      <span style="padding-left:10px;font-size:25px">Style two</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Comment: @Pritesh what *animation* ?

Comment: In this link, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/progress/   see in below "Animated stripes"

Comment: You got Animated Stripes in above link

Comment: @Pritesh both don't support CSS variable, simply use classic value instead

Comment: Sry I didn't get it.

Comment: Hi, This is working fine in chrome but it don't working in edge browser and IE

Answer (score 1):

May below code help you out

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="  
          box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;">
      <span style="padding-left:10px;font-size:25px">Style one</span>
    </td>
    <td style="box-shadow: 20px 19px 26px rgb(112, 173, 71)  inset;">
      <span style="padding-left:10px;font-size:25px">Style two</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```